# How to create a nested select query as a new table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem about writing a nested Select queries in sql.

I tried to devise a new table to show their counts of the tables but I couldn't complete the rest part. I show it as "...."

How can I do that?

Here is the code snippet shown below.

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) AS totalUsers FROM Users u),
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS totalCategories FROM Categories c)
....
```

I want to get this result

```
New Table
totalUsers  totalCategories ...
60                10        ...
```

Comment: Please improve your question. Show the results of your query and what is your expected result or what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @rjs123431 I couldn't complete the query as I have no idea about it. Inner select parts are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a table (but check first if it exists, I leave it up to you)

```
CREATE TABLE CountTable (
    TotalUsers int,
    TotalCategories int
);
```

Then insert the result of your query to the new table:

```
INSERT INTO CountTable  (TotalUsers, TotalCategories)
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) AS totalUsers FROM Users u),
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS totalCategories FROM Categories c)
```